# Assigning a value to innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, html

Looking for a second set of eyes here...

I am calling this function:

```
customPanel(map, "map2", dirn, document.getElementById("path2"), 1);
```

In `customPanel`, I am then building html, then trying to assign it to the page:

Here is the function, the innerHTML is near the very bottom. If I throw an alert before I try to assign the html to the innerHTML of div, it alerts correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map = "";
function customPanel(map, mapname, dirn, div) {
    var html = "";

    function waypoint(point, type, address) {
        var target = '"' + mapname + ".showMapBlowup(new GLatLng(" + point.toUrlValue(6) + "))" + '"';
        html += '<table style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 10px 0px; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); border-collapse: collapse; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">';
        html += '  <tr style="cursor: pointer;" onclick=' + target + '>';
        html += '    <td style="padding: 4px 15px 0px 5px; vertical-align: middle; width: 20px;">';
        html += '      <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker_green' + type + '.png">'
        html += '    <\/td>';
        html += '    <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">';
        html += address;
        html += '    <\/td>';
        html += '  <\/tr>';
        html += '<\/table>';
    }

    function routeDistance(dist) {
        html += '<div style="text-align: right; padding-bottom: 0.3em;">' + dist + '<\/div>';
    }

    function detail(point, num, description, dist) {
        var target = '"' + mapname + ".showMapBlowup(new GLatLng(" + point.toUrlValue(6) + "))" + '"';
        html += '<table style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">';
        html += '  <tr style="cursor: pointer;" onclick=' + target + '>';
        html += '    <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(205, 205, 205); margin: 0px; padding: 0.3em 3px; vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">';
        html += '      <a href="javascript:void(0)"> ' + num + '. <\/a>';
        html += '    <\/td>';
        html += '    <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(205, 205, 205); margin: 0px; padding: 0.3em 3px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">';
        html += description;
        html += '    <\/td>';
        html += '    <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(205, 205, 205); margin: 0px; padding: 0.3em 3px 0.3em 0.5em; vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">';
        html += dist;
        html += '    <\/td>';
        html += '  <\/tr>';
        html += '<\/table>';
    }

    function copyright(text) {
        html += '<div style="font-size: 0.86em;">' + text + "<\/div>";
    }
    // === read through the GRoutes and GSteps ===       
    for (var i = 0; i < dirn.getNumRoutes(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var type = "A";
        } else {
            var type = "B";
        }
        var route = dirn.getRoute(i);
        var geocode = route.getStartGeocode();
        var point = route.getStep(0).getLatLng();
        // === Waypoint at the start of each GRoute
        waypoint(point, type, geocode.address);
        routeDistance(route.getDistance().html + " (about " + route.getDuration().html + ")");
        for (var j = 0; j < route.getNumSteps(); j++) {
            var step = route.getStep(j);
            // === detail lines for each step ===
            detail(step.getLatLng(), j + 1, step.getDescriptionHtml(), step.getDistance().html);
        }
    }
    // === the final destination waypoint ===   
    var geocode = route.getEndGeocode();
    var point = route.getEndLatLng();
    waypoint(point, "B", geocode.address);
    // === the copyright text ===
    copyright(dirn.getCopyrightsHtml());
    // === drop the whole thing into the target div
    div.innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the HTML as requested. It's just two divs:

```
<div class="mapWrapper">
    <div  id="path2"> </div>
    <div  id="map2"> </div> 
</div>
```

To clarify, the path2 and map2 are being generated dynamically by looping through `$_POST` values in PHP.  Here is a snippit:

```
foreach($post_entries as $e){
echo "
<div class=\"mapWrapper\">
  <div  id=\"path" . $increased_counter ."\"> </div>
  <div  id=\"map" . $increased_counter ."\"> </div> 
</div>";
}
```

**EDIT #2**
As requested by @user1090190, a public version of the page:
http://qxxiv6yc.myutilitydomain.com/trip-planned

Comment: Ugh, can't you use some kind of templating system? [This one](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) perhaps?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML? Or better yet, throw up the minimal HTML needed to work with this script at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @etm124 Please remove the excess line breaks from your post to make it easier to read. (I understand they are a copy/paste artifact.)

Comment: Is your code running before the `path2` element exists on the page?

Comment: @amnotiam , I explained how `path2` is being generated. The `path` and `map` divs are being generated by PHP.

Comment: Is div accessible? If you set a breakpoint or log/alert a property of div (such as id) does it display properly?

Comment: @user1090190 , yes, the div is accessible. As you suggested, I placed a break point and I was able to see the id.

Comment: @etm124 well this is a bit of a pickle. Would you be able to throw the page on the web and toss a URL?

Comment: @user1090190 yes, http://qxxiv6yc.myutilitydomain.com/trip-planned/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `path2` has not already been loaded when you call that function. It doesn't matter that you're generating it via PHP.  You have to wait for the DOM to load in the browser first before you can reference specific elements.  There are two solutions to this:

1. Call the function after page load.  I.e.

   ```
   <body onload="customPanel(map, "map2", dirn, document.getElementById("path2"), 1);">
   ```
2. Put all your Javascript at the bottom